# Easiest way to set up LDAP for dev testing

Tags: ldap

I'm a developer for a product that integrates with LDAP for authentication. I need to set up a directory that I can test against.

I'm not an expert with LDAP. To help ease the learning curve it'd be useful to have a real-world example directory.

Are there any resources that'll help me set up an demo directory, ready-to-go? A VMware appliance for example?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Any OS. Last time I had to do this, I struggled to set up AD on Windows. OpenLDAP may be easier?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[OpenDS](http://www.opends.org) is very easy to get running - just download the ZIP file and run the installer or use the Java web-start.  The installer can populate the directory with test entries too if you want to see some example data.

**Edit (2020):** [OpenDJ](https://www.openidentityplatform.org/opendj) is the successor to OpenDS after Oracle closed it down, but I haven't tested it to see if it has the same easy installation with sample data. Give it a try.

I'd strongly recommend [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) as a good client to use to get familiar with how to browse, edit and manage data via LDAP.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. The automatic test data is a big help. Thanks!

Comment: Note: OpenDS only works with Java7. For Java8, you'll need the OpenDS fork OpenDJ.

Comment: Is this library "alive" or a extinct relic now? (Year 2020). Thanks.

Comment: OpenDS link no longer works. Can you please update it?

Comment: I've linked to OpenDJ now as that looks to be the successor to OpenDS. Untested though, leave a comment if you try it out.

Comment: I confirm that OpenDJ allow you to auto-populate the created server with any number of users you want

Answer (score 9):

Install Ubuntu Server Edition 8.10, boot it up and install OpenLDAP.

```
$ sudo apt-get install slapd ldap-utils
```

You can probably just accept the defaults if this is just for testing, therefore your domain will be *dc=example,dc=com*.  In the install wizard it should ask you to setup your ldap admin user, this user's DN should be *cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com`.

Then you'll need to add two organizational units, one for People, one for Groups. Create the file myldap.ldif and place into it this:

```
dn: ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: people

dn: ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups
```

If LDAP is running, shut it down with `/etc/init.d/slapd stop`.

Use *ldapadd* to add the LDIF file to our LDAP database:

```
$ ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com -W -f myldap.ldif
```

It will ask you for your password that you set during the install.

Fire LDAP back up with `/etc/init.d/slapd start` and then install Webmin:

```
$ sudo aptitude install perl libnet-ssleay-perl openssl \
                        libauthen-pam-perl libpam-runtime \
                        libio-pty-perl libmd5-perl
$ wget http://garr.dl.sourceforge.net/sourceforge/webadmin/webmin_1.441_all.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i webmin_1.441_all.deb
```

You can now navigate to your LDAP server's IP at port 10000 using URL `https://your-server-ip:10000/`.  Note you will be required to enter the root password for the computer at this login screen.

From here we need to configure Webmin to interact with our LDAP environment. Expand "System" and then select "LDAP Users and Groups." Click "Module Config" at the top of the page and find the following option and enter this custom data:

```
Base for users  ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
Base for groups     ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
```

Click save at the bottom.  You will be returned to the previous screen where you can now add LDAP users and groups.  This is now a functioning LDAP server.  You can query it from the command using *ldapsearch*:

Whole database:

```
$ ldapsearch -x -h <your-server-ip> -b "dc=example,dc=com"
```

User search:

```
$ ldapsearch -x -h <your-server-ip> -b "dc=example,dc=com" '(uid=blah)'
```

I did most of this from memory so you'll have to forgive me if I missed a couple steps.
Enjoy.

Comment: This answer looks pretty good still, in 2022. I recently installed on Ubuntu 20.04 for testing, and the steps I followed look the same as these, although instead of Webmin I chose to use ldap* commands and Apache Directory Studio. I recommend sticking with example.com if it is only for testing/learning, as I had issues when I tried another domain.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think any LDAP server is gonna be easy until you brush up on your LDAP a little; most of the concepts are shared across them.

For Windows it might be worth your while looking at [Active Directory Application Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/adam/default.mspx), which gives you fairly basic (but comprehensive enough for development requirements) LDAP functionality without all of the Domain/DNS/etc baggage that comes with full AD.

Comment: The link in your answer is broken. Is there any way you can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

ForumSys provides a free LDAP test server for this very purpose! Just connect to it with your favorite language to test your auth code, no need for any set up, check it out: https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/